# Python Pandas - New Column Returns earliest data for each unique ID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a data set with three columns (Customer ID, transaction, date).  There is a one to many relationship between Customer ID and transaction.  I want to add in a new column that contains the earliest purchase data for each unique Customer ID.  I tried the code below

```
df['First Purchase Date'] = df.loc[df.groupby('Customer ID').Date.idxmin(),:]
```

but when I run this code I receive an error that says During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: And then finishes off with a Value error. It also doesn't create a new column called First Purchase Date.

Is there a simple way for finding the earliest data in a column given criteria in another column?

I've also tried using min()

```
df['First Purchase Date'] = df.groupby(['Customer ID'])['Date'].min()
```

This code creates a new column unlike the first idxmin line I mentioned above but it gives "NaN" as the value for everything.

Comment: read the stackoverflow guidelines. you should post a minimum example with code and data, that shows the error, and also post the error itself. otherwise you will get downvotes

Comment: additionally, the exceptions have valuable information telling you what you did wrong in your code. you should read them carefully

Comment: What do you mean by exceptions?   I did post the code above. is that not sufficient? What else would you need?

Comment: first, the error you got, you should always read it, and publish the full error with your questions. second, you published _some_ code, but not enough to run and reproduce your issue. you need to post a minimum example that shows the error.

Comment: and btw, notice the answer below should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the code you need

```py
min_dates = df.groupby(['Customer ID'])['Date'].min()
df['First Purchase Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: min_dates.loc[row['Customer ID']], axis=1)
```

here's how it would look in a minimal working example:

```
csv = """Customer ID,Date
1,2019
1,2018
1,2020
2,2000
2,2010
2,2005"""
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))

min_dates = df.groupby(['Customer ID'])['Date'].min()
df['First Purchase Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: min_dates.loc[row['Customer ID']], axis=1)
print(df)
```

this is the output

```
    Customer ID Date    First Purchase Date
0   1           2019    2018
1   1           2018    2018
2   1           2020    2018
3   2           2000    2000
4   2           2010    2000
5   2           2005    2000
```

Comment: Thanks Aviad.  Although I've included it in my code and it works I don't completely understand it, especially the second line.  Do you have any suggestions on what I can read in order to get a better understanding of this.

Comment: you need to understand how pandas indexes work. the `df` has one row per transaction, and the `min_dates` has one row per `Customer ID`. so you can't just assign from one DataFrame to the other. read more pandas tutorials and the documentation for indexing and .apply. you will get the hang of it